# Printf in scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp

How would I do something like the following in scheme?

```
printf("I went to the park at %d with %s", 4, "Bob");
```

The closest I have right now is:

```
(define TIME 4)
(define NAME "Bob")
(display "I went to the park at ") (display TIME) (display " with ") (display NAME) (display ".")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this in standard Scheme. Many Scheme implementations have a `format` procedure that is modeled on the [Common Lisp `format`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_format.htm). For example, Chez Scheme has a pretty complete implementation of `format`, and also `printf` which is just a wrapper around `format`. I am so used to using `format` that I never think to use `printf` in lisps:

```
> (format #t "I went to the park at ~A with ~A~%" 4 "Bob")
I went to the park at 4 with Bob
> (printf "I went to the park at ~A with ~A~%" 4 "Bob")
I went to the park at 4 with Bob
```

Here `format` sends the output to the current output port when the first argument is `#t`; `printf` automatically sends output to the current output port. [Common Lisp style format directives](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_c.htm) are prefixed with a tilde (`~`). The `~A`, or aesthetic, directive prints objects in human-readable form, and is what you want most of the time. There are other directives for formatting numbers; I added the `~%` directive, which emits a newline. Your original example did not include a newline, and `printf`, at least in C, does not add a newline at the end of output (ordinarily this is desirable). The `format` procedure should allow much more control over results than the mother of all `printf`s, namely C's `fprintf`.

The specific facilities for printing formatted output will depend on the implementation, but Chez Scheme, MIT Scheme, Gauche Scheme, and Guile all implement `format`. Chicken Scheme implements `format`, and also implements `printf`, `fprintf`, and `sprintf` which all use the same format directives as `format`. Racket has a host of formatted output procedures, including `format`, `printf`, and `fprintf`; all of these use Common Lisp style format directives, too.

You will have to consult the documentation of a specific implementation to understand which format directives are supported and how they work; the Chez Scheme documentation contains some information, but suggests consultation of the Common Lisp HyperSpec for complete documentation.

There are also [SRFI-28 (Basic Format Strings)](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-28/srfi-28.html) and [SRFI-48 (Intermediate Format Strings)](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-48/srfi-48.html) which provide some of this functionality to implementations that support them.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what Scheme interpreter you're using. For example, in Racket you can use `printf` for a similar effect:

```
(printf "I went to the park at ~a with ~a" 4 "Bob")
=> I went to the park at 4 with Bob
```

Check the [documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._fprintf%29%29) for more formatting modifiers.